# Requesting help for mysql division query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query on following table. However, not really getting the expected result. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

"Find employee SSno for those employees who work for at least all those departments that the employee with SSno 444505555 works for".

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with your attempted query.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT empSSNO
FROM 
    <YourTableName> 
WHERE 
    dno in (
        SELECT 
            dno 
        FROM 
            <YourTableName> 
        WHERE 
            empSSNO = '444505555'
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. However the query requirement is to include ALL department the reference employee works. This query will return result if only one department matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try and check if this works:

```
select empSSno, GROUP_CONCAT(dno) as dnos from your_table where dnos like CONCAT('%',
(select GROUP_CONCAT(dno) as dnos from your_table where empSSno == '444505555' GROUP BY empSSno)), '%') GROUP by empSSno
```

One assumption which I am taking here is that the dno for employees are entered in the sorted order in the table. For example for every employee, dno 1 would come before dno 2.